# drop-list dar valores de la base de datos

Tags: jsp, dropdownlist

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? quiero que los items del select me muestre los datos que tengo en la base de datos pero me sale error

***jsp***

```html
   
   <select  name="perfil_" id="perfil_" required="required"> 
                <%
                   String driver ="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
                   String url = "jdb:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE ";
                   Class.forName(driver);
                    String sql = "SELECT PERFIL FROM REGISTRO;";
                    Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next() == true) {
                %>
                <option><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                <% }
                %>
```

***error***

> java.sql.SQLException: argumentos no válidos en la llamada
>
> descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no
>   pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
>
> excepción javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException:
>   argumentos no válidos en la llamada
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:180)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> causa raíz java.sql.SQLException: argumentos no válidos en la llamada
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
>     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:145)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

*Nota: La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario del servidor.*

Comment: el string del url tiene un espacio al final, será eso?

Comment: hola ya lo cambie y no es eso